# Yii2 undefined namespace error

Tags: yii

I am new to YII framework. My whole code is correct but undefined namespace error is present. Please set the error.

**model**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

 use yii\base\Model;
```

**view**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

?>
```

**controller**

```
namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use app\models\UserForm;
```

**error**

```
Undefined namespace filters

Undefined namespace web

Undefined namespace models
```

Comment: When do you get this error. What are you trying to do at that point. Provide the code relevant to the action being processed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using advanced applocation of Yii2. If so, it is better to use `namespace frontend\models;` or `namespace backend\models;` relative where those file is located